# MJPEG(?), how smart is the browser?

Tags: caching, memory, mjpeg, ip-camera

I am trying to interface with a IP based camera, of this type:

[CVUL-I125](http://www.chinavasion.com/ip-cameras/power-over-ethernet-ip-camera-with-angle-control-and-motion-detection-black/)

This has two ways of retrieving the video feed:

- through http://ipaddress:188/videostream.cgi
- and through http://ipaddress:188/snapshot.cgi

The second simply returns a single JPG file.

The first, however, is the one I'm wondering about.

If I simply point my browser to that url, it shows an image, that keeps updating, quite fast actually, but the page never seems to stop downloading, as expected.

My question is this: Will the browser consider this in the same way it would consider an animated gif with an infinite number of frames? Meaning, will it cache this image and simply keep on downloading it, hoping at some point it can start "playing" it back from the beginning?

Simply put, will this slowly (or fast) fill up my browser memory and/or cache?

I'm asking because I'd like to put this program on a mobile device, and if the stream is cached, I simply can't do that. With the snapshot image I can simply retrieve it and display it, but I know of no other way to display the stream than to use a web control, and thus my question.

I started downloading the stream feed and paused it, and looked at it, and here's an excerpt from the Google Chrome temporary file:

```
--ipcamera^M
Content-Type: image/jpeg^M
Content-Length: 27958^M
^M
```

So, it looks to me as a JPG file, but it keeps updating, so I assume this is MJPEG?

Comment: The content is likely to be `M-JPEG`, as it is typical for IP cameras. Not sure about the browser though, one the one hand the browsers seem to support this content type, `multipart/x-mixed-replace`, and present only the last frame inline, however it is up to the browser to decide whether to disk-cache the stream or not.

Comment: I guess I should just test it, monitoring memory usage then.